# Defining a linear operator and its adjoint in an optimization problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I'm interested in solving the following minimization problem:

$$ \min_X ||XD-b||_2^2 + ||X||_* $$

Where $D \in R^{n\times1}$, $ X \in R^{n\times n}$ and $b \in R^{n \times 1}$. That last term is the nuclear norm of $X$. I'm reading through [this paper](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2009/03/2268.pdf) and they formulate the above problem in a more generalized way:

[image]

where $A(X)$ is a linear operator. They also define the adjoint as $A^*$. Now, when they differentiate the first term, they wrote it as:             [image], which I don't understand is that how the adjoint operator involved in the derivative. If we assume that $A(X) = XD$, then the derivative of $.5||A(X) - b ||_2^2$  is $D^T(A(X) - b)$

My question: Are the adjoint linear operator $A^*(X) = D^TX$ and the linear operator $A(X) = XD$ correct definitions? I am getting error in my simulation so I am expecting I didn't correctly define $A$ and $A^*$

Comment: If you are just dealing with real matrices then $A^{*} = A^{T}$.

Comment: @AsAnExerciseProve yes they are real matrices. So the adjoint operator is the transpose of the output of the linear operator $A(X)$? If so, how would you define $A(X)$?

Comment: Let $f: H_{1} \to H_{2}$ be a linear operator, then $f^{*}(x)$ needs to satisfy, $< f(x) | y > = < x | f^{*}(y)>$. What I was saying before about a matrix $A$ is that if $f(x) = Ax$ then $< Ax | y > = < x | A^{T}y>$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint. So you need $<XD | Y> = < X | \mathcal{A}^{*}(Y) >$, this all depends on what is the inner product. From what you wrote (The $||X||_{*}$ term) you are using some specific type of norm and therefore inner product.

Comment: The defining property of the adjoint operator is that $\langle A(X), Y \rangle = \langle X, A^*(Y) \rangle$ for all $X, Y$. If $A(X) = DX$, then $\langle A(X), Y \rangle = \langle DX, Y \rangle = (DX)^T Y = X^T D^T Y = \langle X, D^T Y \rangle$. This reveals that $A^*$ is the linear transformation defined by $A^*(Y) = D^T Y$.

Comment: @littleO This is an answer to my question.